# Не работает сервер Node.js + socket.io, прерывается CORS

Tags: node.js, сокет, socket.io, cors

Я пытаюсь написать сервер на Node.js, но CORS прерывает передачу данных. я уже что только не перепробовал, чтобы это исправить, но ни расширения, ни заголовки, ни т.п. не помогло.

Выводит ошибку

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Помогите пожалуйста)

Код сервера:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'] // Разрешаем только GET и POST запросы
  
  }
});
```

Comment: `cors: { origin: true, credentials: true },`